# Sending sms from android application

Tags: android, sms

I have this code for sending sms to cellphones .
However it doesn't seem to deliver the sms, am i missing something ? should i buy some account from cellular companies ?

```
public void sending (View v) 
{
    String messageToSend = "this is a message";
    String number = "1234567890";
    try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, messageToSend, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried to send sms to my number many times,i used my number as "1234567890" using it as i dial it every day, then i tried using it with the international code "+9721234567890"

thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578689/sending-text-messages-programmatically-in-android

Comment: What (if anything) are you testing on? Device? Emulator?

Comment: Does that tablet happen to be in possession of a valid SIM card? :)

Comment: If the device you're testing on doesn't support SIM or UIM (or whatever it is...) cards, then you'll not be able to send/receive texts, without the use of some third party app like: What's App, or Viber etc etc, and even then, I doubt you'll be able to inject into those.

Comment: ah okey that i didn't know thanks