# Send SMS in android with adding sms data to SMS phone db

Tags: android, sms

I try to send SMS programmatically follow to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578689/sending-text-messages-programmatically-in-android).

SMS is sending fine, but sms content, actually my sms text do not save into phone messages db 
**and** when i open SMS app on my phone, i do not see my sended message.

So the question : is there any way to saving message in phone SMS db after send him programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **found a good example** where you can **read the messages that was sent/ received** by the user.

Here's how the code goes :

**This is for security stuff :**

```
public class StringCryptor 
{
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final String RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
    private static final int RANDOM_KEY_SIZE = 128;

    // Encrypts string and encode in Base64
    public static String encrypt( String password, String data ) throws Exception 
    {
        byte[] secretKey = generateKey( password.getBytes() );
        byte[] clear = data.getBytes();

        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
        cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( clear );
        String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString( encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT );

        return encryptedString;
    }

    // Decrypts string encoded in Base64
    public static String decrypt( String password, String encryptedData ) throws Exception 
    {
        byte[] secretKey = generateKey( password.getBytes() );

        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
        cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );

        byte[] encrypted = Base64.decode( encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT );
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal( encrypted );

        return new String( decrypted );
    }

    public static byte[] generateKey( byte[] seed ) throws Exception
    {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
        SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance( RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM );
        secureRandom.setSeed( seed );
        keyGenerator.init( RANDOM_KEY_SIZE, secureRandom );
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        return secretKey.getEncoded();
    }
}
```

And then,

When you **receive** any message, here how it goes :

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";
    public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";

    public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String PERSON = "person";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String READ = "read";
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
    public static final String BODY = "body";
    public static final String SEEN = "seen";

    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT = 2;

    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_READ = 1;

    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_SEEN = 1;

    // Change the password here or give a user possibility to change it
    public static final byte[] PASSWORD = new byte[]{ 0x20, 0x32, 0x34, 0x47, (byte) 0x84, 0x33, 0x58 };

    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) 
    {
        // Get SMS map from Intent
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String messages = "";

        if ( extras != null )
        {
            // Get received SMS array
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );

            // Get ContentResolver object for pushing encrypted SMS to incoming folder
            ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

            for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i )
            {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

                String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

                messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
                messages += body + "\n";

                // Here you can add any your code to work with incoming SMS
                // I added encrypting of all received SMS 

                putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );
            }

            // Display SMS message
            Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

    }
```

**For saving the data :**

```
private void putSmsToDatabase( ContentResolver contentResolver, SmsMessage sms )
    {
        // Create SMS row
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put( ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress() );
        values.put( DATE, sms.getTimestampMillis() );
        values.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ );
        values.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus() );
        values.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX );
        values.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN );
        try
        {
            String encryptedPassword = StringCryptor.encrypt( new String(PASSWORD), sms.getMessageBody().toString() ); 
            values.put( BODY, encryptedPassword );
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        // Push row into the SMS table
        contentResolver.insert( Uri.parse( SMS_URI ), values );
    }
```

Now, **to read the values that were stored in the db**,

```
public void onClick( View v ) 
{
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null);

    int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.BODY );
    int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.ADDRESS );

    if ( indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst() ) return;

    smsList.clear();

    do
    {
        String str = "Sender: " + cursor.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" + cursor.getString( indexBody );
        smsList.add( str );
    }
    while( cursor.moveToNext() );


    ListView smsListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.SMSList );
    smsListView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList) );
    smsListView.setOnItemClickListener( this );
}
```

Basically, in this case, then you click refresh, the listview will update with the latest values.

I hope this answers the question.

Comment: No problem.. I was just sharing some good information ..m glad it helped.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to store the message into the SMS store:

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("address", number);
    values.put("body", message);
    values.put("read", readState);
    values.put("date", dateTime);
    mActivity.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

Note that this won't be supported from Android 4.4 on, if your app isn't registered as [default SMS app](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#SMS) (see chapter *SMS Provider*).

Edit: Added missing closing parenthesis

Comment: If this method do not works on 4.4, is there any other method to add SMS to db?

Comment: No, your app has to be registered as default SMS app in order to insert/update/delete messages into/from the SMS store. p.s. check this as well: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: I think `readState` is `0` or `1` and `dateTime` is a `Date` instance :) p.s. check out this: http://sermojohn.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/sms-content-providers-and-delivery-reports/