# The code for the prompt after using sendTextMessage

Tags: android

I want to develop a project to send text messages in android using `sendTextMessage()` from `android.telephony.SmsManager`. When the message is sent a prompt appears. I want to know where can I find that code?

Comment: Why you are asking for code with out showing what you have tried ??

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
      String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

      try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have not search it:

Question : [Sending text messages programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578689/sending-text-messages-programmatically-in-android) already exists.

you can try this code also:

```
public void sendLongSMS() {

    String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
    String message = "Hello World! Now we are going to demonstrate " + 
        "how to send a message with more than 160 characters from your Android application.";

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message); 
    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
}
```

Code for Toast(prompt)

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

- [Sms Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)
- [Toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Read this : [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before asking question here.

Comment: I know the code to send sms from android and its working properly, I want to make some changes in android.telephony.SmsManager file so please suggest  how to do it, I added that file in my project but its not working.