# How to know my message is received or not in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

[image]

As in this capture it's really obvious , if I want to send a message from phone(1) to phone(2)
how to know these Operations:

1.my message is received or not into phone(2)?

2.my message is read or not into phone(2)?

and I know how to send message in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578689/sending-text-messages-programmatically-in-android)

but here I want to know these operation above , do we have a broadcast to these operations?

Comment: you can get send and delivery report, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589642/sms-delivery-report-in-android. but you can't know that "message is read or not into phone(2)".

Comment: thanks it's really so awesome , but really it's impossible to SMS read Report ?