# How can i send SMS from my android app?

Tags: android

I am trying to send an SMS from my android app. Every time I click on my button, it goes to `catch` part rather then `try`.

Here is my method:

```
Button sms = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    sms.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {

                    Log.i("Send SMS", "");
                    Intent sms = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    sms.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
                    sms.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
                    sms.putExtra("address", new String(con));
                    sms.putExtra("sms_body", "Test SMS to Angilla");

                    try {
                        startActivity(sms);
                        finish();
                        Log.i("Finished sending SMS...", "");
                    }
                    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this,
                                "SMS faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: have u add permission ??

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34488582/5733111)

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

Comment: @NiravRanpara That permission is not necessary to send an SMS with another app.

Comment: @NiravRanpara already did that.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send sms two ways:
 1. SMS Manager
 2. Built in app

Both ways need permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Example with sms manager:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

Example with built-in app:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(phoneNumber)));
startActivity(intent);

Comment: It's working (with built-in app), but this is not working "Uri.encode(phoneNumber)" 
i also tried "intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + con));

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Your message");

try {
    startActivity(sendIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```