# Delay after pressing a button

Tags: android, button, connection, delay

After I press a button, Android parse a JSON file and pick the info it needs. Until yesterday, I was using an external library created by a user and it worked perfectly. But now, I don't want to depend on him, so I've searching info about Google's GSON. I've implemented this library with no problem, but now, after pressing the button that opens a new activity there's a delay.

This delay is due to the connection and parsing that are done **before** the activity shows.

How can I force the app to wait the Internet connection until de Activity is shown? It's a lil bit uncomfortable because after pressing the button, it seems that the app has frozen, but after all data is loaded, the new activity appears.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using AsyncTask in your activity and tranfer all operation into background showing a dialog to user until everything is loaded and appears to user.

Comment: does your ui depend on the json data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AsyncTask or Handler for network operations. Do *never* put "long time" operations into the UI thread

Comment: Sorry but sandy replied before you. Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Actually I answered first. To be accurate 2mins -_-. But thats not a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [asyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).. and if server communication is a success then show the new Activity or else exit..

Comment: You replied first so, you get the accepted answer. Working like a charm! :D

Comment: I'm sorry but I wanna be fair, @207 replied before

Answer (score 1):

it is possibl;e via Handler and AsyncTask  see this [How to set delay in Android onClick function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199191/how-to-set-delay-in-android-onclick-function) you will get how to use Handler and see this for Asynctask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644567/need-a-simple-example-for-android-asynctask