# How to prevent continuous press a button in short time in android?

Tags: android, button

I got a error caused by user press a button too fast in a short time.
The following is the error:

```
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115): ANR in test.test.test (test.test.test/.testActivity)
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115): Load: 3.94 / 2.98 / 2.63
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115): CPU usage from 5863ms to 0ms ago:
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   5.6% 36/nandd: 0% user + 5.6% kernel
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   1.7% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 1.7% kernel
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   1.5% 89/mediaserver: 1.5% user + 0% kernel / faults: 14 minor
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   1% 5780/com.inno.wordcard: 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 34 minor
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   0.8% 115/system_server: 0.3% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 8 minor
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   0% 4933/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   0.1% 176/com.android.systemui: 0.1% user + 0% kernel
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   0.1% 1440/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115): 93% TOTAL: 2.9% user + 9% kernel + 81% iowait
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115): CPU usage from 217ms to 736ms later:
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   7.6% 36/nandd: 0% user + 7.6% kernel
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):   3.8% 115/system_server: 0% user + 3.8% kernel
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):     1.9% 116/HeapWorker: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115):     1.9% 149/InputDispatcher: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
06-27 12:46:51.500: ERROR/ActivityManager(115): 100% TOTAL: 0% user + 11% kernel + 88% iowait
```

How can i prevent the problem like that?

Comment: please explain it a bit more further. cudn't get you.

Comment: @ting fu sit : Disable the button on the first press/click - is that too difficult to work out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199191/how-to-set-delay-in-android-onclick-function please look at this to see if the top answer can work for your app

Comment: If webservice call is there, then **AsyncTask with ProgressDialog (Not cancellable)** is the best solution

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling a web service after the button is tapped ?
There are several options:

1.Add a progress dialog that will disable anything in the background.If it is a web service this is the best solution.

2.Disable any UI element in the screen for the time period that you are performing any action.

3.Spawn a new thread or an async task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Boolean Variable for prevanting to run your code on every button click as:

```
boolean isClicked=true;
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(YourId);
btn.setonClickListener(listener);
public onClickListener listener = new View.OnclickListener{
      onclick(View v){
      if(isClicked==true)
      {
        isClicked=false;
        doWork();
        //DO YOUR WORK HERE...
      }
      else
      {
        // DO NOTHING...
      }
      }
}
 public void doWork(){
      /// YOUR CODE HERE...

         //USE AsyncTask ,Hanlder,handlerThread, or Thread for performing long running         task in background on button click
        isClicked=true;


     }
```

Comment: quite pointless, because if `doWork()` does not return, `onClick()` does not get called again.

Comment: @lenik : any example when doWork() not return , if you are using return "xxxx" in doWork()?

Comment: his main problem is the `onClick()` handler which does not return in time, hence the `keyDispatchingTimedOut` error. the correct solution will be offloading work into another thread.