# Capture sequential images in time-lapse

Tags: android

I am working with the camera on an Android device. I have captured some images and uploaded them to http. 
I used an Intent to invoke an existing Android camera application

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

I have Button:

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    int response = uploadFile("sdcad/" + myLocation
                            + ".jpg");
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    String upLoadServerUri = "...";
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
        return 0;
    }
    try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP
                                                            // connection to
                                                            // the URL
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of
                                                        // maximum size

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage
                + ": " + serverResponseCode);
        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }

        // close the streams //
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        // dialog.dismiss();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "MalformedURLException",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // dialog.dismiss();
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    // dialog.dismiss();
    return serverResponseCode;
}
```

Now I would like to to capture sequential images in time-lapse, upload these. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Just put a timer inbetween image captures or delayed function? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199191/how-to-set-delay-in-android-onclick-function